# Broadcast receiver not working in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying the system broadcasts and custom too. Both don't seem to post the toast message which will indicate success. There seems to be an obvious mistake that I'm not able to spot. Thanks in advance!

Manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ai.serna.chargerautooff">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="ai.serna.chargerautooff.DONE_TEST">
                </action>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>`

   </manifest>
```

MyReceiver:-

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        Toast.makeText(context,"Receved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Receved");

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    }
```

Comment: You won't get the `BATTERY_CHANGED` or `HEADSET_PLUG` broadcasts for a Receiver registered in the manifest. Those are both special broadcasts that need to be handled a little differently. Beyond that, how exactly are you sending your custom `DONE_TEST` broadcast?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent("DONE_TEST");
            i.putExtra("Time","Done!");

            sendBroadcast(i);

Comment: It needs to be the exact same, complete action `String` that you have in the manifest - `Intent i = new Intent("ai.serna.chargerautooff.DONE_TEST");`

Comment: woah! that worked! thanks a lot

Comment: can you please help me on how to use the BATTERY_CHANGED broadcast?

Comment: Should I use services?

Comment: I'm trying to find a decent example, but the gist of it is, you need to register it dynamically on a `Context`; e.g., on an `Activity`, or a `Service`, if that's what you're going for. If you're familiar with the `registerReceiver()` method, then that's what you need to use, and doing that in a `Service` will work. `BATTERY_CHANGED` is also a sticky broadcast, so if you don't need to monitor it constantly, you can actually just call `registerReceiver()` as needed with a null `BroadcastReceiver` to get the current stats.

Comment: Sure thanks a lot for your help!